# Swift_TransportException error in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to create a contact form that email the message to my email address. When I tested it out I got this error

> Swift_TransportException
>
> Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. bv17sm3597476wib.13 - gsmtp "

This is my controller

```
public function contact()
{

     $data = array(
                'name' => Input::get('name')
                );


            Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message){
                $message->to('test@gmail.com', 'Nikki')->subject('Login Details');
            });
}
```

and this is my contact.blade.php

```
{{ Form::open(array('id' => 'contact-frm', 'class' => 'contact-form', 'route' => 'contact')) }}
{{ Form::label('fname', 'Name') }}
{{ Form::text('fname') }}

{{ Form::label('surname', 'Surname') }}
{{ Form::text('surname') }}

{{ Form::label('email', 'Email') }}
{{ Form::text('email') }}

{{ Form::label('message', 'Message') }}
{{ Form::textarea('message') }}

{{ Form::submit('Submit') }}
{{ Form::close()}}
```

mail.php

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'port' => 587,
'from' => array('address' => 'myEmail@gmail.com', 'name' => "Nikki"),
'encryption' => 'tls',
'username' => 'myEmail@gmail.com',
'password' => 'MyPassword',
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
```

Comment: Please show your mail configuration. Seems you did not set it appropriately

Comment: I've updated my question to have the mail.php

Comment: did you try to use gmail's SSL instead of TLS? (ssl/ port 465 )?

Comment: I got this error "Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Operation timed out #60]"

Comment: oh, well, another option about this issue is to try to set `encryption => ''`.

Comment: Well, I just checked out one of my projects. I am using the option with the ssl, like this: `'driver' => 'smtp','host'=>'smtp.gmail.com', 'encryption'=>'ssl', 'port'=> 465`

Comment: you can try this process. This worked for me


  http://stackoverflow.com/a/31193005/2503722

Answer (score 4):

In Laravel 5, the problem comes from the `.env` file. Laravel ships with a value set for encryption there that overrides your default setting in `config/mail.php`. In `.env`, change `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null` to `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 3):

When changing the `.env` you need to restart your server

Answer (score 2):

change your mail driver in .env file "smtp to sendmail" it works in my case.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
```

every time after change .env file clear config

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.env` file.

> I was using *mailgun*

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=1230
MAIL_USERNAME=user@domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=your_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

MAILGUN_DOMAIN=user@domain.com
MAILGUN_SECRET=null
```

I had the same problem, My fault was `MAIL_ENCRYPTION` was given a wrong input.

Answer (score 0):

When changing the `.env` you need to restart your server or in linux terminal runs

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: The question does not say anything about a ".env". Perhaps you can clarify what that is, why you think it has been changed, and how your suggested solution works.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was migrating project to the new server (Ubuntu 20.04), so I have to install

> sendmail

by following command -

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
```