# How to Configure Laravel 5 default Forget Password( Swift_Mailer) for a Google Mails Account?

Tags: laravel-5, swiftmailer

I want to use the Laravel 5 default `Swift_Mailer` for "`Forget Password`".
I tried to edit `.env` file providing the following details, but it is still not working:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
```

Do I need to modify any other details or files?

Comment: This helped me.. Thanks

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100877/trying-to-get-laravel-5-email-to-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the values also in your config/mail.php. There are also examples and it is more failsafe.