# Laravel 5 email reset password

Tags: php, email, smtp, laravel-5

I´m new using Laravel 5 when I try to send an e-mail through my website running Laravel 5 Authentication service for reset the password, I get this exception:

Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 x14sm43954igx.1 - gsmtp
"

Here is my env configuration

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=GaBqPkX42wJuSzsmCPe0AM8Qx4AXAhAf

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=course
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp-relay.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=pass
```

what´s wrong?

Thanks for your support!

Comment: Did you take a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100877/trying-to-get-laravel-5-email-to-work? It would be helpful. Any reason to use 'smtp-relay.gmail.com' rather than 'smt.gmail.com'. Just guessing

Answer (score 0):

I believe your server is reading the mail server details from config/mail.php file please edit it and fill in the details there also. Comment if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try, Allowing less secure apps to access your account. -> "Turn on. (Note to Google Apps users"
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255