# Laravel:What changes needed to reset the password

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, reset-password

i want to send a link to a mail address to reset the password. but it is showing "Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required"

my .env is like this

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=asmtp.unoeuro.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=hello@google.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

my reset.blade.php is like this

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ password/reset/, [$token] }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                   <!--  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}"> -->

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ $email or old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Reset Password
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

my mail.php is like this

```
   <?php

   return [


   'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

   'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'asmtp.unoeuro.com'),


  'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

  'from' => [
    'address' => 'hello@example.com',
    'name' => 'Example',
  ],

  'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),


  'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),


  'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

  'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

 ];
```

what changes i need to make to send a mail and reset the password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to make correct `MAIL_USERNAME` and `MAIL_PASSWORD`.

You can follow given link([Trying to get Laravel 5 email to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100877/trying-to-get-laravel-5-email-to-work)) for more detail.

Hope this work for you!

**UPDATE**
Please once you can clear the cache:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: i saw that but still couldn't find any solution

Comment: I hope you performed clear cache after my suggested change applied. If not, See *UPDATE*.

Comment: thnx it worked. i cleared cache but didn't do the config:cache now it is working fine..thnx

Answer (score 0):

Just like *AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd* said, it clearly says "530 5.7.1 Authentication required" which essentially means your mail credentials are incorrect. Also, try looking for the type of encryption and ports used by your mail provider.