# Sending mail error in laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5.1

i am trying to send email in laravel 5.1
but it give me folloiwng error.

Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError o1sm938569pgf.63 - gsmtp
"
following is my .env configuration

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME= <my gmail email id>
MAIL_PASSWORD= < my gmail password > // here i also try the app password which one created in 2 Step verificaton 
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

i have tried 2-Step verification and https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps also trun on. But still getting the error

anyone can help me for that?

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29237075/1739852 ensure you restart your server and/or run `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: yes i tried that every time when i changed in .env

Comment: i  have updated my question and provided my configuration in .env file, if anyone can help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to get Laravel 5 email to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100877/trying-to-get-laravel-5-email-to-work)