# Laravel 5.5 does not send e-mails

Tags: php, laravel, email

Hello I try send email from my registration script to user ([link](https://www.5balloons.info/user-email-verification-and-account-activation-in-laravel-5-5/)). I have config file:

`config/mail.php`

```
return [

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 's44.linuxpl.com'),

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'verify@coins.webmg.pl'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    'username' => env('verify@coins.webmg.pl'),

    'password' => env('MySecretPassword'),

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
    'stream' => [
        'tls' => [
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
        ],
    ]
];
```

And file `.env`:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=s44.linuxpl.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=verify@coins.webmg.pl
MAIL_PASSWORD=MySecretPassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Script to send mail from `RegisterController.php`

```
protected function create(array $data)
{

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    $verifyUser = VerifyUser::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'token' => str_random(40)
    ]);

    $sendMail = Mail::to($user->email)->send(new VerifyMail($user));

    return $user;
}
```

Class `VerifyMail`

```
class VerifyMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $user;

    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.verifyUser');
    }
}
```

And file to send `verifyUser.blade.php`

```
<h2>Welcome to the site {{$user['name']}}</h2>
```

I don't know what is wrong in this configuration, because I can log in correctly to the mailbox, so the email address and password are correct. Additionally, laravel does not return any errors, the script itself is executed correctly.

Comment: I swap my smtp details with my gmail credentials because I know that that smtp is working and if the issue still exists I know something is wrong with my code else issue with my smtp.

Comment: @DhavalChheda OK, but in Gmail I have two factory Auth SMS, whether with such account security, smtp will work ?

Comment: @michal Since the `Mailable` class is using the `Queable` trait, is the default queue listening to jobs?

Comment: @AbishekRSrikaanth Probably yes, the full file `VerifyMail.php`, look like this: [link](https://pastebin.com/SZH2UB5v)

Answer (score 1):

**Restore your `mail.php` file to its defaults:**
**Replace:**

```
'username' => env('verify@coins.webmg.pl'),
'password' => env('MySecretPassword'),
```

**with**

```
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
```

You misunderstood how the `env($key, $default = null)` method works. The first argument it takes is the *key* of the environment variable (eg. 'MAIL_USERNAME'), and the second argument is the *default* value (which can be optional).

Store your mail credentials in the **`.env` file only**, and never within your config files' `env()` calls.

[Laravel Docs: Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#environment-configuratio)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. The problem is with file `.env`. The file was loaded with previous settings. It was enough to clean the cache files.

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Here it is well described [Trying to get Laravel 5 email to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100877/trying-to-get-laravel-5-email-to-work/31193005#31193005)

Answer (score 0):

just restore your config/mail.php to default one and try to set the below values in your laravel .env file directly

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=abc@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=abc@123
```

May wish this will help you Thanks