# I'm failing to send mail with swift mail using gmail SMTP

Tags: php, laravel, gmail, swiftmailer

I am getting this error

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at\r\n
530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError 14sm769143wmo.27 - gsmtp\r\n
```

I have used php artisan config:cache and restarted my server but i still get the error.

Heres my config/mail.php details

```
 'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => [
            'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'Example@gmail.com'),
            'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
        ],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

      'username' => env('Example@gmail.com'),

        'password' => env('******'),
```

Heres my UserController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function sendMail()
    {


        \Mail::send('emails.welcome', array('Test'=>'Test User'),
        function($message) 
        {
            $message->from('Example@gmail.com', 'Your Application');
            $message->to('Example@gmail.com', 'Test')->subject('Your Reminder!');        
        });
        echo"Mail sent successfully...!";
    }
}
```

Here's my view file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>hello, {{{$Test}}}!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

My .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER= smtp
MAIL_HOST= smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT= 587
MAIL_USERNAME = Example@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD = ******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION = tls
```

How can i get this to work??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100877/trying-to-get-laravel-5-email-to-work

Answer (score 0):

Set smtp details in .env file, not in config file. see the code

```
env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp')
```

so this env() function is getting data from .env file, so set your values there. not in config. or if u want to set in config file, set like this

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
```

and so on.

Comment: ive got the credentials already in my env file but i still get that error

Comment: then its your authentication error as error is also suggesting, check for password, plus enable your email to be used by less secure apps.. google for this.

Answer (score 0):

Change your .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=Example@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=Example@gmail.com
```

I think that port 587 and encryption tls can't be used again. maybe the tls certification is not valid