# I cannot send email using gmail even though I already allowed less secure apps | Laravel

Tags: laravel, email

I have an observer that fires off an event if a user updated his email address.

```
public function updated(User $user)
{
    if($user->isDirty('email')){
        $new_email = $user->email; 
        $old_email = $user->getOriginal('email');

        //dd($user);
        event(new UserUpdate($user, $old_email));
    }
}
```

In the UserUpdate event I have the following inside the constructor:

```
public function __construct($user, $old_email)
{
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->old_email = $old_email;
}
```

In the event listener, I want to send an email to the old email address.

```
public function handle(UserUpdate $event)
{
    $user = $event->user;
    Mail::to($event->old_email)->send(new UserUpdated($user));
}
```

And the Mail class looks like this:

```
public function __construct($user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

public function build()
{
    $this->subject("Updated Email");
    return $this->view('emails.updatedUser');
}
```

When I update the user, I get the following error:

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required
```

I setup the email in the .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=example@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

in the mail.php I also edited a few details:

```
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),

'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'example@gmail.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Admin Email'),
],
```

I went to my email and enabled the option to allow less secure apps.

How can I get my emails to work?

Comment: What's the error while sending email

Comment: it's in the question @SagarGautam
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required

Comment: Please find out the solution is here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100877/trying-to-get-laravel-5-email-to-work

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100877/trying-to-get-laravel-5-email-to-work) question as a reference, I then noticed that all I needed to do was to restart my server and clear cache.