# Swift_TransportException when when user register

Tags: php, laravel, pyrocms

I'm building my website using PyroCMS and it gives me an error when user submit his/her register form.

```
Swift_TransportException
Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified. ]
```

By searching about this error I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36187597/6570409) answer. But it didn't worked for me.

Follow is my .env file fields. Is this problem with these configurations or else?

```
APP_ENV=local
INSTALLED=true
APP_KEY=app_key
APP_DEBUG=true
DEBUG_BAR=false
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=pyrocms
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD="123"
APPLICATION_NAME="Default"
APPLICATION_DOMAIN=127.0.0.1:8001
APPLICATION_REFERENCE=default
DEFAULT_LOCALE=en
APP_TIMEZONE=Asia/Colombo
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8001
ADMIN_USERNAME=admin
ADMIN_EMAIL=dilushadasanayaka@gmail.com
ADMIN_PASSWORD=password
```

Comment: Do you have the env variable related to swift? Do you use Swift?

Comment: Looks like your server is not configured to use Swift mailer. Try configuring it or using SMTP or alternate email driver per Laravel documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Reason for this error was I forgot to configure email setting as @Ryan said. Error was fixed when I configured my mail settings. In my case I had a gmail account. So add followings to my `.env` file.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=yourEmail
MAIL_PASSWORD=yourPassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

You can read a comprehensive blog about laravel mail settings from [here](https://learninglaravel.net/learn-to-send-emails-using-gmail-and-sendgrid-in-laravel-5).